# Can kinetic friction be negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, coordinate-systems, free-body-diagram

[image: 1]

In this diagram, $m=3 \;\text{kg}$, $g = 9.8 \;\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$, $\mu_k =0.4$, $F = 100 \;\text{N}$ and $\theta=60°$.

Now, acceleration of $m$ in the direction of $x$-axis (direction of $F\cos\theta$) is equal to $a$. The acceleration in the $y$-axis is zero, so $R+F\sin\theta=mg$ and thus $R=mg-F\sin\theta$.

Now, $$F_k = \mu_k R = \mu_k (mg-F\sin\theta) \\ ma=F\cos\theta-F_k \\ a=\frac{F\cos\theta - \mu_k (mg-F\sin\theta)}{m}$$

Everything is fine up till now and $a=24.29 \;\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$ (for the given data). But my problem is with $F_k$. In this example, it becomes negative, as $F_k = \mu_k (mg-F\sin\theta) = 0.4(3 \times 9.8 -100\sin60°) = -22.88 \;\text{N}$.

My question is that is this possible? If not, what would actually happen for given data? Or the given data is wrong somewhere?

Comment: This is probably a case where the author solved it and then put random numbers in without thinking. Vincent Thacker already answered. But in theory, you can think of the block as being wedged between two surfaces: the math doesn't know any better. For this set of numbers, it would mean that the block is grinding on the top surface. Friction would still point leftward, however. Your main mistake is in your prescription for the kinetic friction. It's magnitude is not $\mu_k N,$ but it is $\mu_k |N|$, and it always acts leftward for this example.

Comment: His answer is so exact and correct might as well just green check it save us time. Just imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed not possible, as $F\sin\theta$ clearly exceeds the weight $mg$ of the object. Therefore, there is a net force upwards and the object will lift off the surface. Since the object is no longer in contact with the surface, there will be no friction.

> Can kinetic friction be negative?

It certainly can. In this context, positive/negative is an indication of direction and depends on the choice of coordinate system. If you chose the $x$-axis to point towards the left instead, the friction will become positive. The point is that the direction of friction is opposite to the direction of motion, which is a statement that doesn't depend on the choice of coordinates.